# Update an entity obtained from Select in HQL

Tags: java, hql

say I have obtained a list of class objects from a SELECT statement like

```
List<MyClass> something = em.createQuery("SELECT m FROM MyClass m").getResultList();
```

and I called a few setters

```
for (MyClass thing : something)
thing.setName("a name");
```

What is the syntax to update these class objects back to the database?
Do I write something like `UPDATE MyClass m SET m = :newObject . setParameter("newObject", thing);`

This is purely about the update syntax, although I know the manager is able to pickup the changes and write those back to the database for me.

Thanks

Comment: if the setName() is invoked in the same hibernate session in which you get the **something**, the update be automatic process after session closed. or you can use em.saveOrUpdate(**thing**) to merge the change back into DB.

Answer (score 0):

are you using traditional hibernate or hibernate JPA implementation?
with traditional hibernate, yourSession.saveOrUpdate(**thing**) should work
if your code is running with JPA hibernate implementation, use em.merge(**thing**);